# How to find polygons in a given set of points and edges?

Tags: math, geometry, computer-science, computational-geometry

Consider the following problem:

Given N points in plane and M line segments connecting them, find all polygons (convex or concave) that do not contain any other polygons inside.

For instance:
[image: Example]

There are 5 polygons founded:

1 - 2 - 5 - 6

2 - 3 - 5

3 - 4 - 5

7 - 8 - 9

10 - 13 - 20 - 12 - 11

How can I identify these polygons and there corresponding vertices and edges? And what is the fastest solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build graph with segment ends as vertices and segments as edges, then find cycles using [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Note that the same edges might belong to multiple cycles (polygons) like your `2-5` and there might be many variants to select cycles. To exclude ambiguity, you can build [fundamental set of cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis)

Edit. As weston noticed in comments, resulted polygons might contains others. So sketch of more geometric approach:

Build lists of adjacency for graph.
Sort edges in ever list by polar angle.
Choose the most bottom vertex A.
If it's degree is 0, remove vertex, if 1, remove vertex and edge.
Otherwise get edge E with the smallest angle from this vertex.

Walk to pair vertex B.
Choose the most left edge F from B.
Move along to F edge into C.
If dead end, remove F and vertex C and return to B.

Repeat moving using left-hand rule until meet vertex A or dead end vertex.
In the walk process remove edges outgoing from vertices of degree 2 or mark them as used.

Comment: I know it's accepted, so OP's happy with it. But I'm a little unclear still, can you explain how it excludes polygons that contain others?

Comment: @weston Graph approach could not help to choose the best polygon set from geometric point of view without additional (perhaps complex) efforts. It was not important for my task exploiting similar approach (covering points by any polygon)

Comment: Could you maybe clarify the algorithm a bit more or maybe even help us with a pseudo code? Because I also can't seem to find other similar algorithms on the internet.

For instance, the most bottom vertex, does that mean the one with the smallest angle or rather the one with the lowest y coordinate? Also the most left vertex being the one with the lowest x coordinate?

Another thing which i was missing is that "degree" really means the degree of a vertex (i.e. the number of edges), not the polar angle in degrees.
Removing the edge means removing it from both adjacencyLists?

Comment: Then vertex B is concluded by A + E or otherwise the left hand rule (i.e. increased polar angle)? What means the most left edge F then? The one pointing the most to the left? 

And then the algorithm is always to pick the next left vertex and then always apply this "degree removal rule"? or only remove degree 2 or larger edges then?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: @MeFisto94 The most bottom vertex is 12 (min Y). The most left edge after 20-13 is 13-10 (last one on CCW order). Yes, remove edge from adj.list. Algorithm traverses "the most inner" polygon