# Fill contour created by line segments

Tags: algorithm, opengl, mesh

I calculated the intersection of a mesh and a plane. As output I got an array of line segments, rendering the lines gives me the intersection contour. Now I would like to fill the area enclosed by the contour. The problem I'm facing is the line segments are not in any particular order. I am using OpenGL for rendering.

Comment: Order them to a closed line loop and triangulate the resulting polygon. Performing geometric operations is nothing OpenGL will do for you.

Comment: Could you please suggest some fast algorithm to do the same? I was hoping there are some concept similar to opengl tessellation which could help me with this problem

Comment: Can someone tell me what wrong with this question that people are voting down?

Comment: Your question is poorly formulated and someone needs telepathy to understand it. Look at Edit section http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245408/ - is it what you asked?

Comment: Because it's too unclear what you are doing. In you intersect a general mesh with a plane, there is not even a guarantee that all the intersections form closed polygons. This is only valid for closed meshes. And even then there are potentially multiple areas.

Comment: The algorithm @MBo linked is a good starting point. But just from the intersection contours it will be impossible to find the correct intersection region. For example, the intersection of a torus with a plane can yield two circles as intersection contour. But how should any algorithm know that the inner circle should not be filled?

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++ libraries for geometry processing like [VTK](http://www.vtk.org).

Assuming that you are intersecting a closed mesh with a plane, you should get one or more closed polylines. You can get what you want by following these steps below:

- First, you will have to merge points that are overlapping, to create a contiguous polyline or a set of multiple closed polylines. This will be erroneous based on the tolerances you use. But that is part and parcel of geometry processing.
- Second, you will have to pass individual polylines (closed loops) to a triangulation algorithm like Delaunay triangulation (vtkDelaunay2D). You must also pass the line segments of the polyline as a constraint on the output triangulation.

The problem is that this will not work in all cases, because it is hard to know, which side is inside and which side is outside, while filling the polylines. But it is a starting point.

Another more robust approach can be to use a dense mesh of the plane while computing intersection with the object. During intersection, you can compute if the vertex of the plane-mesh is inside or outside the object. In this manner you can keep track of which regions to fill.